# lateinit property variantName has not been initialized error while building android project with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

When an android app which uses com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha06  tools is build using the command line (gradle build) with gradle 6.8.1 or 6.8.2, fails by saying

*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  **lateinit property variantName has not been initialized**
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 3s*

Is there any workaround for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the gradle plugin in the app-level build.gradle file to "7.0.0-alpha07", and it should be solved.

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha07"
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems in your code there is a variable named "variantName" that has not been initialized yet. Please share your code if you still face any issue.

Comment: Same problem here. And, there is not an variable called variant name in my code :-(

Comment: It is the source code of android build tools at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/refs/heads/master